# Minispy driver - user mode call

Tags: driver, kmdf, usercall

After hours of spending on installing drivers, I began looking at minispy 
driver:

[Windows-driver-samples/filesys/miniFilter/minispy/](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/minispy)

I am trying to catch all the calls of user to open files. I was trying to do it with all the parameters it prints (like Opr, Major Operation...) but I can't filter it in exact way.

How can I filter only the user calls (open file)??
How can I determinate within the code if the user called the transaction?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

look for [`FLT_CALLBACK_DATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544620(v=vs.85).aspx)`.RequestorMode` - if you use minifilter.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It seems like this is what im looking for.
The thing is, it seems it's always NULL as i'm trying to print its value but nothing displays:
 if (Data->RequestorMode)
 {
  DbgPrint("mode %d\n", Data->RequestorMode);
 }
Maybe I'm using it wrong?

Comment: EDIT:
It always prints the value 1 which i guess is the kernel mode?

Comment: @user3449011 - 0 this `KernelMode` and 1 is `UserMode` - look in `wdm.h` `enum MODE` . if you use code - `if (Data->RequestorMode) { DbgPrint("mode %d\n", Data->RequestorMode); } ` of course it will be always print 1. remove `if (Data->RequestorMode) ` statement

Comment: Yes I changed it to:
if( Data->RequestorMode != NULL).
But it is still always 1. Even when I open a text file (for example) I suppose it should print 0. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user3449011 - are you know c/c++ at all ? you understand what your `if` statement do ?

Comment: Checking RequestorMode is not empty. Whats the problem with that?

Comment: @user3449011 - o my god