# MiniFilter - How to detect only User initiated i/o activities?

Tags: windows, filesystems, driver, minifilter

I need to detect only User initiated i/o activities.
When I say User I actually mean User (double click to open file, enter, 
etc).

Data->RequestorMode == 1, prints only User mode and I need User initiated actions.

So, I need to know how to print only transactions made by user itself. (Open file, 
double click, enter, etc... as said before)

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you double-click a file, you are asking Explorer to take an action on your behalf.  Explorer does so by examining the file's extension, looking up the application associated with that extension, and launching it with instructions to open the file.

The Windows loader is responsible for loading the application into memory and setting it running.  In order to do so it must open at least the executable and usually one or more DLLs.  Once the application starts up, it might also open some configuration files before it opens the file the user asked for.

All of these open operations are performed in the same context.  The kernel knows which process initiated the file open, but it has no way to tell whether it was opened by the Windows loader or by the application itself, or to distinguish between a configuration file and the file the user double-clicked.  So you are not going to be able to detect user-initiated file open operations from a file system filter driver.

It might instead be possible to use a Windows Explorer extension, although this will only work for files that are opened using Explorer or one of the standard dialogs, i.e., for most but not all applications.

Answer (score 0):

> Data->RequestorMode == 1, prints only User mode

so

`if (Data->RequestorMode == UserMode) DbgPrint("%x\n", Data->RequestorMode);`

print only `UserMode`

or I be say better - `if UserMode print UserMode` - print only `UserMode` ..

Comment: I will give an example to better explaine myself:
Let's say I open a abc.txt file. The user mode calls will be:
Open a bunch of dll's, open notepad, open abc.txt.
I want to filter this and catch only the abc.txt (or anything else that user acutaly opened). How do I catch only what the user (the human) open? Like double click and Enter)

Comment: @user3449011: you can't.  Windows only knows that a program is opening a file, there's no way for it to tell whether it is opening a file because the user explicitly asked it to or for some other reason.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - really OP try found from user or kernel mode was request. and he can not understand what is - `FLT_CALLBACK_DATA.RequestorMode` - begin at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292697/minispy-driver-user-mode-call

Comment: The example he provides in the comment above shows that he is trying to distinguish between files opened by the user and files opened by software.  I believe that his earlier question was just a bit confused because he didn't understand what "user mode" actually means.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - `if (Data->RequestorMode) { DbgPrint("mode %d\n", Data->RequestorMode); }` "It always prints the value 1" - how you think are can this code print value 0 ? this is only c/c++ question for understand statement `if (Data->RequestorMode)`

Comment: You've misinterpreted the question, that's not what he's asking about.  He's saying that the debug statement runs for both `abc.txt` and for `notepad.exe` and he wants it to only run for `abc.txt`.  (The misunderstanding is not your fault; the question was not written very clearly.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - but OP can not understand why `if (Data->RequestorMode) { DbgPrint("mode %d\n", Data->RequestorMode); }` never print 0 (`KernelMode` ) - but because `if (Data->RequestorMode)` - we never go to print, when `RequestorMode == 0` because `if`. I say at begin - simply remove `if` before print. however this is very common task in drivers - when we check `RequestorMode` (`KernelMode` or `UserMode`) and based on this do different (say more strictly params checking or allow/denny access)

Comment: *but OP can not understand why if (Data->RequestorMode) { DbgPrint("mode %d\n", Data->RequestorMode); } never print 0* - I understand why you think this, but I'm absolutely certain it isn't what the OP actually meant.

Comment: ok, may be my poor English here is problem. but I based on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292697/minispy-driver-user-mode-call